# What is the probability to choose uniformly a subset of an even size from $\{1,2,3,...,n\}$

Tags: probability

Let $A=\{1,2,3,...,n\}\subset\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Let $X\subset A$ be a subset of $A$. The probability to choose $X$ is uniform: $P(X)=\frac{1} {2^n}$. I am required to calculate what is the probability that the size of $X$ is even.

**My Attempt**

If the uniform probability to choose $X$ is $P(X)=\frac{1} {2^n}$, I can conclude that the number of subsets of $A$ is $2^n$. I did not study combinatorics, so I have no idea why is this true, but I do know that the number of subsets of $A$ of size $k$ is $\binom{n}{k}$, and  that $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom{n}{k}=2^n$ (according to the binomial theorem). So I can live with that.

Now I have 2 problems:

- If the total number of subsets of $A$ is $2^n$, then according to my calculations, it means that the empty set $\emptyset$ is also a subset of $A$. Is that correct?
- The probability I am required to calculate is:

$$\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}\binom{n}{2k}$$

But unfortunately I don't know how to compute the sum.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Note that if you have an odd subset $V$, then $V\oplus\{1\}$ is even. ($\oplus$ is XOR). So, half of the subsets are even.

Answer (score 1):

There are $2^n$ subsets because for each of $n$ elements you have an independent binary choice whether to include it in the subset or not, so according to the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) there are $2^{n}$ possible choices.

About your first problem: Yes, that's correct, the empty set $\emptyset$ is a subset of $A$.

About your second problem: That sum isn't the probability that you want. You wrote down the probablity of choosing a subset that contains at most half the elements.

To find the probability of choosing a subset with an even number of elements, consider the operation that toggles the membership of some fixed element (say, $1$) in the subset. That is, if $1$ is in the subset, the operation removes it, and if it isn't, it adds it. Note that this sets up a one-to-one correspondence between subsets of even and odd sizes. You can conclude that there are equally many subsets of either parity, and hence the probability of choosing a subset of either parity is $\frac12$.

Comment: Essentially, XOR with $\{1\}$.

Comment: @DonThousand: Yes, but that didn't strike me as the level at which the OP thinks about sets.

Answer (score 1):

To see that there are $2^n$ subsets of $[n]$. There is the following bijection between these subsets and binary words.

Given a subset of $[n]$ reocrd a $1$ if $i$ is in the set and a $0$ if it is not.

To get subsets of even size we need to calculate the following sum
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{ \lfloor n/2 \rfloor }\binom{n}{\color{red}{2} k}.
\end{eqnarray*}
This easily done using the binomial theorem
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{ n }\binom{n}{ k} =(1+1)^n=2^n \\
\sum_{k=0}^{ n } (-1)^k \binom{n}{ k} =(1-1)^n=0. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Add these equations and divide by two, so there are $2^{n-1}$ subsets of even cardinality. Thus the probability that a subset of the power set has even cardinality is $1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

It is not difficult to prove that for every positive integer $n$ for  set $A_n:=\{1,\dots,n\}$ we have the equality: $$|\{X\subseteq A_n\mid B\text{ has even cardinality}\}|=|\{X\subseteq A_n\mid B\text{ has odd cardinality}\}|$$

For this *induction on $n$* is very handsome.